# property of vuex-class namespace didn't work thouth I had add namespaced:true in my module

Tags: typescript

I use vue,typescript to build my project,in which I also use vue-class-componnet,vue-property-decorator,vuex-class.Both vue-class-component and vue-property-decorator work well,vuex-class not.There always has an error like "vuex.esm.js?2f62:993 [vuex] module namespace not found in mapState(): global/",in which global is one of my module state.

firstly,I have export my module state like this:

```js
export default {
    namespaced:true,
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
};
```

and export my store like this:

```js
const store: Store<any> = new Vuex.Store({

  modules: {
    //添加自定义模块
    user
  }
})

export default store
```

this didn't work at all.
sencondly,I tried to let module state wrote in store,

```js
const store: Store<any> = new Vuex.Store({

  modules: {
    user:{
      namespaced:true,
      state:{
        foo:'this is foo'
      },
      getters:{
        getFoo(state){
          return state.foo;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It didn't help anything~The same error occurred.

This is my directory structure:

```
-src
 -store
  -global
   -index.ts
  -index.ts
 -views
  about.vue
```

store/global/index.ts :

```
import { Module, ActionTree, MutationTree, GetterTree } from 'vuex';
import { GlobalState } from './types';
import { RootState } from '../types';

/**
 * state
 */
export const state: GlobalState = {
  version: '1.0.0',
  token: '',
};

/**
 * getters
 */
export const getters: GetterTree<GlobalState, RootState> = {
  getVersion(state: GlobalState): string {
    return state.version;
  },
  getToken(state: GlobalState): string {
    return state.token;
  }
};

/**
 * mutations
 */
export const mutations: MutationTree<GlobalState> = {
  setVersion(state: GlobalState, payload: string) {
    state.version = payload;
  },
  updateToken: (state, payload: string) => {
    state.token = payload;
  }
};
```

store/index.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex, { StoreOptions } from 'vuex';
import { RootState } from './types';
import { global } from './global';

Vue.use(Vuex);
const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = {
  state: {
    version: '1.0.0',
  },
  modules: {
    global,
  }
};
export default new Vuex.Store<RootState>(store);
```

views/About.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="demo2">
    <h1>{{txt}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import Home from './Home.vue';
import { State,Getter,Action,Mutation,namespace } from 'vuex-class';
// import { UserInfo } from '../store/modules/user';
// const namespace = 'global';
const global = namespace('global')
@Component({
  components: {
    Home,
  },
})
export default class About extends Vue {
  //props
  @Prop() private msg!:string
  @Prop() private sum!:number
  //data
  txt:string = 'hhhjj'
  dt:string ='ddd'
  //computed
  get getTxt(){
    return this.txt
  }
  //methods
  private add():void{
    this.sum ++
  }
  //watch 
  @Watch('txt')
  changeTxt(newTxt: string, oldTxt: string){
    console.log(`change txt: ${oldTxt} to ${newTxt}`)
  }
  @State("version") version!:string 
  @global.State("version") globalversion!:string 
  mounted(){
    console.log("version",this.version)
    console.log("globalversion",this.globalversion)
  }
}
</script>
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env env_config=dev webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.config.js",
    "build:prod-fastLoan": "cross-env env_config=prod webpack --config build/webpack.pro.config.js",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "tep": "node scripts/template"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.11.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.15.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.10.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.22",
    "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

However, maybe the problem is that namespace cannot be found, should I 
 need to define my own interface in the *.d.namespace file?And how?I tried to add the following code,but nothing change:

```
declare module 'vuex-class' {
  function namespace(k:string):any
}
```

If there is anybody to help me with this problem,I would be glad,since I have searched on the website for solutions somemany times and found out nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but it may be related. With the latest VueX versions, your state should be a function:

```
export const state = () : GlobalState => {
  return {
    version: '1.0.0',
    token: '',
  }
}
```